# how to use the function of from_string in z3_solver which is one of the api in z3PY

Tags: z3, z3py

```
from z3 import *
x = Bool("x")
y = Bool("Y")
s = Solver()
formula = 'And(x,y)'
s.from_string(formula)
```

When I try to run this code, the compiler mentions me that "z3.z3types.Z3Exception: b'(error "line 1 column 1: invalid command, '(' expected")\nunsupported\n'". Which form should the 'formula' be, the smt2.0 or the python shape. Could you help me solve this question?

Comment: SMT2! It comes with various restrictions however, e.g. it may require you to declare all variables in the string too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the input in the SMTLib2 language, and also make sure all the variables are declared. Here's a working example:

```py
from z3 import *
s = Solver()
formula = """(declare-const x Bool)
             (declare-const y Bool)
             (assert (and x y))
          """
s.from_string(formula)
print(s.sexpr())
print(s.check())
print(s.model())
```

This prints:

```
$ python a.py
(declare-fun y () Bool)
(declare-fun x () Bool)
(assert (and x y))

sat
[y = True, x = True]
```